# Shifting Parabolas Question about equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question about shifting parabolas. The equation is to shift  $$f(x) = x^2$$
$$to$$ $$g(x)=(x-6)^2$$

Now I know that the formula is $(x-h)+k$ so that the $6$ moves to the right as in $-(-6)$.

My question is, on the first equation $x$ is raised to the power of $2$, while on the second equation not only $x$, but also $-6$ is raised to the power of $2$. Why is the correct answer "to get the function $g$, shift $f$ right by $6$ units" instead of $36$ as in raised to the power of $2$.

Comment: Oh yes. I love the downvotes.

Comment: i also, it is the right answer $$g(x)=(x-6)^2$$ moves $f$ 6 units to right

Comment: Yes, but why isn't it raised to the power of 2? @_@

Comment: if we expand it then we have $$g(x)=x^2-12x+36$$ you got also a term $-12x$

Comment: Wait what, how did you get -12x here..

Comment: after the binomial formula $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

Comment: Notice that $g(x) = f(x - 6) = (x - 6)^2$.

Comment: Mr Taussig, could you please explain why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $z$. When we send $z$ through $f$, we get $f(z)=z^2$. To get the same "output" from g, we can input $z+6$, since $g(z+6)=((z+6)-6)^2=(z+6-6)^2=z^2=f(z)$.

Since $z$ was just some arbitrary number, what we did above should work for other inputs.  So to get the same result from $g$ as we do from $f$, we input a value to $g$ that is 6 greater than that which we put through $f$.

If $g$ were $f$ shifted 36 to the right (which it is not), we would have
$f(z)=z^2=g(z+36)=((z+36)-6)^2=(z+30)^2$ for all $z$.